# Rolling up dependent probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, statistics, data-science

I have a model with features and labels in a dataframe with columns like:

```
[id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_1, label_2, label_3]
```

Here the labels are 1, 0 for True, False.  I build a model for each label independently so,

```
model_1: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_1]

model_2: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_2]

model_3: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_3]
```

So in the end I have 3 models that I can use to predict each label type and I can get
probabilities between 0 and 1 if the label_1 (2 or 3) are True/False for each row.

I want to roll up these probabilities to a single score.  The problem, however, is that these are dependent.  So if I treat them independently, I run into a situation where I might get

```
[label_1, label_2, label_3] = [1.0, 1.0, 0.001],  0.99*0.99*0.001 = 0.0001
```

Now the problem here is that sometimes what we need to predict might already have label_1 and label_2 but not label_3 so we just predict label_3.  This rollup score is way too small because label_1 and label_2 are known and are True but the rollup will say that they are false - but we may not be that confident in our prediction of 0.001.  To deal with this I am using the geometric mean

```
(1.0*1.0*0.001)^(1/3) = 0.10
```

This seems to work okay but I am wondering if there a better way to to deal with this?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, having to do with how to express information about relationships as conditional probabilities. As such it's off topic here, try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Exactly how it all shakes out depends pretty strongly on assumptions about how the inputs and label variables are related, in particular the relations among the labels. Is label_1 present, label_2 present, label_3 absent pretty common? If so then consider building a model for label_3 which takes the other labels as inputs; this is equivalent to a specific assumption about how they're related.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have

```py
import statistics as stats 

p1 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
p2 = [1.0, 1.0, 0.001]
```

**Geometric mean:**

```py
stats.geometric_mean(p1)  # 1.0
stats.geometric_mean(p2)  # 0.10000000000000002
```

But with the **arithmetic mean**

```py
stats.mean(p1)  # 1.0
stats.mean(p2)  # 0.667
```

Implemented for more precision:

```py
def am(ps):
    return sum(ps)/len(ps)

am(p1)  # 1.0
am(p2)  # 0.6669999999999999
```

Makes more sense, so I would use **arithmetic mean** instead of geometric one.